# Bash echo output mix of string and character

Tags: linux, bash, echo

I am taking an assessment and stumbled across the following sample question, but when I run the line it's none of the options?  Which is the correct answer?

[image]

Comment: That looks like PHP, not bash.

Comment: PHP uses `.` for string concatenation.

Comment: @Barmar I see, is this valid bash syntacs as well or no?

Comment: Yes. `.` has no special meaning in bash, so it will just be echoed literally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That code looks more like PHP. `.` is the concatenation operator, and it can be used with both strings and numbers (it will convert the number to a string). The output will be

```
Tomorrow will be January 3rd
```

In `bash`, `.` has no special meaning, so it will be echoed literally. The `echo` command puts a space between each argument, so the output will be

```
Tomorrow .  will be January  . 3 . rd
```

Answer (score 0):

`.` is the string concatenation operator for PHP. In bash, you could just do `echo Tomorrow will be January ${num}rd`.

Both versions of the code output `Tomorrow will be January 3rd`.

Comment: Where did the `num` variable come from?

Comment: I just put that there to show you how you would reference a variable in a bash string.